# Godaddy and Azure CDN CName

Tags: azure, cname, azure-cdn

I have a custom domain name www.customdomain.com and created the CName record on Godaddy to point www to the Azure CDN url aaa.azureedge.net. On the CDN, there is an index.html file. Now, when I put www.customdomain.com/index.html to the browser, it works great. However, when I put www.customdomain.com only, it shows 404. Any idea how to make it point to www.customdomain.com/index.html when www.customdomain.com is accessed?

Regards
Hammer

Comment: Did you see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413300/azure-cdn-default-document-index-html ?

Comment: Tks. Hard to believe, compared to AWS, Azure surprisingly still does not have such a basic feature.